# Is there a voice speaking when Tony creates the new element in "Iron Man 2"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

In *Iron Man 2*, Stark creates a new element. The moment after, when he turns off the beam and the focus is on the triangle, it sounds like a voice is saying something.

Is there any info about that?

Comment: I've left the tags for now but why is that tagged with _Infinity War_ and _Endgame_? (as the question only seems to tackle IM2)

Comment: Ehh JARVIS maybe?

Comment: I tagged it because I’ve read other opinions that Stark created an Infinity Stone in Iron Man 2. If he did would that connect to the Infinity War story line?

Comment: At the moment in question, the only voice I hear is Tony saying "Huh, that was easy".

Comment: Before he said “that was easy” The sound or voice sounded primal.

Comment: In the order of the sounds that we hear: the machine turns off making some weird *cricket-like* sound. That, is most likely the metallic parts of the machine contracting whilst cooling. its one of the most common sounds we hear when the heaters at home turn off/on. After that, Tony whispers "that was east".

Comment: At the 3:07 mark is where I here a voice. It almost sounds like “yes” in a growl like voice.

Comment: @Kevin - I hear it. Then again, it may just be [EVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_voice_phenomenon)

Comment: this is very very very very similar to the "i have telepathy" thing that floated around a few weeks ago from the Endgame trailer. Its just some background sound.

Comment: The hissing sound may be the sound of coolant venting or something. I don't hear "yes".

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a voice, it's the AI Jarvis congratulating Tony on creating the new element.

Comment: Oof. Got any source confirming it's not just a sound effect? That's not obvious... :/

Comment: Jarvis definitely says "congratulations, you have created a new element" (circa 3:31) but I don't think that's what the OP is asking about.  In the comments Kevin says the putative voice is at 3:07.

Comment: This isn't the "voice" that OP is referring to.

Comment: I have listened to the scene again, there is no other voice present.